# Can anyone help me with the identification of this mark which is located on the bottom of my porcelain bowl?

Tags: translation, meaning, character-identification, traditional-characters, seal

This underglaze mark assumed to be Chinese is located beneath a fine porcelain bowl that I own. I have no clues as to the actual translation.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It could be "壹峰".

Answer (score 1):

It is 寿峰 /shòu fēng/

It means "Longevity Peak"

Most likely a brand name (manufacturer)

Comment: Thank you for your help Tang Ho.  I am very grateful.

Comment: A brand in Japan.